# jQuery function not working when content changing

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, append, live

I'm using this function in order to add a div inside an element,

```
(function() {
        $('.p-item').append('<div class="p-info-wrap"></div>)';
}) ();
```

I also having a filterable gallery using 'quicksand' plugin in the same page. Inside the gallery, I have elements with above mentioned class(p-item). When I sort the gallery, the contents are changing and suddenly above appended div is Disappearing.

Help me keep the div alive even the gallery is sorted.

Regards.

Comment: Is the sorting built in or are you custom sorting?  What is the structure of the elements getting sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function at the end of sorting process

```
function addDiv() {
  $('.p-item').append('<div class="p-info-wrap"></div>)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if quicksand provides any hooks like post-sort events and such, but here is a generic way you can solve this problem:

```
var doMod = true;
$('#tree')[0].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if (!doMod) { return; }
    doMod = false; // Supress handling of subtree event
    $('#tree').append('foo');    
    doMod = true; // Restore the doMod flag
});

$('#tree').html('<p>New content</p>');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8dUSJ/

The 'DOMSubtreeModified' event is deprecated, though, and it's supposed to be superseded by [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver). I don't have much knowledge about the latter, so refer to documentation. It seems to have questionable browser support.

EDIT:

Just so we're clear about this: the above solution won't keep the DIV 'alive'. It will only allow you to readd it after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your code at the end of the `append()`, you have a `'` outside not inside of the `append()`.

```
(function() {
    $('.p-item').append('<div class="p-info-wrap"></div>)';
})();        //------------------------------------------^-----here is the issue.
```

Try this: **http://jsfiddle.net/T8VC4/**

```
(function() {
    $('.p-item').append('<div class="p-info-wrap"></div>');
})();
```